# How can I get "ViewData["x"]" value in OnActionExecuted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need verify value in ViewData,and i want get ViewData value in OnActionExecuted,how can i get it;

I use Aspe.net core mvc 2.2.

maybe like:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    if (ViewData["SubHeader"] == null)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the [`ActionExecutedContext.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutedcontext.result?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutedContext_Result) property to [`ViewResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and access its [`ViewData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult.viewdata?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewResult_ViewData) property:

```
if (context.Result is ViewResult viewResult)
{
    if (viewResult.ViewData["SubHeader"] == null)
    {

    }
}
```

The check for whether or not `context.Result` is a `ViewResult` means actions that don't return a `ViewResult` will pass through without error.